# How to create a search function in this C++ program

Tags: c++, c

I'm writing a small program with a command-line interface. In this program I want to have a search function which I managed to create.

But it for a character search for the first name but I want to create the same function which will be able to search using the "Student Registration number".

The Search Case where I'm having problems:

```
int kWord;
stdDetails  stdFind;
cout<<"Enter the Student Registration Number of the Student: ";
cin>>kWord;
for(int x=0;x<i;x++){
  stdFind = stdDetailsStructs_0[x];
  if(!strcmp(kWord,stdFind.stdNum)){
    search=1;
    break;
  }
}
if(search==1){
  display(stdFind);
}else{
  cout<<"Student details not found please try again."<<endl;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't read that code even if you set bounty worth 5000. Btw, try using STL. It will probably help you.

Comment: ok guys I'll just edit it and put the search part only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If its just a number why cant you use `==` operator instead of strcmp.

Comment: yes u r right that's where I'm going blank can't get mind how to do it I need to use == but don know how can u help please.

Comment: `if(kWord==stdFind.stdNum)` instead of `if(!strcmp(kWord,stdFind.stdNum))`

Comment: and yes also make `search=0` in else part

Answer (score 1):

I don't think kWord should be `int` as the student registration numbers should be strings. If they are numbers you should use `==` for checking equality.

Where is `search` declared?

If it's a global, you should have

```
if(search==1){
  display(stdFind);
}else{
  cout<<"Student details not found please try again."<<endl;
  search = 0; // <-- add this
}
```

Comment: Good point there on the student registration number, expand on that a bit why they should be strings even if it has "number" in the name.

Comment: Student registration number should be of String type to avoid any accidental arithmetic being performed on it.

Comment: We should think about 'kind of data' rather than data-type when deciding about such things

Comment: Would look nice to expand that in your answer when you say they should be strings so Ill just upvote and pretend it is.

Answer (score 1):

stdNum is of type int in structure stdDetails.So use `==` operator insted of `strcmp()`

```
                    int kWord;

                    cout<<"Enter the Student Registration Number of the Student: ";
                    cin>>kWord;
                        for(int x=0;x<i;x++){

                        if(kWord==stdDetailsStructs_0[x].stdNum)                       
                        {
                            search=1;
                            break;
                         }   
                        }
                        if(search==1){
                            display(stdFind);
                        }else{
                            cout<<"Student details not found please try again."<<endl;
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

use--- if (kWord == stdFind.stdNum),,,,
strcmp() is for String Comparison.
kWord and stdNum are integer values.

Answer (score 0):

I would use strncmp() (even though it's really C style and you could use the STL) because it is probally failing all the time because of the '\n' at the end of the line.

if stdNum is actually a string:

```
if(!strncmp(kWord,stdFind.stdNum, strlen(stdFind.stdNum))){
```